# Searching for multiple strings

Tags: python, regex

I have the following Python code:

```
string = '[subscript=hello] this is some text [subscript=hi again]'
superscripts = re.findall(r'\[subscript=(.+?)\]', string)
print superscripts
```

and it returns `['hello', 'hi again']` which is the text which I want, however, I would rather instead of returning this, I would prefer it to replace the string so that it returns `<sub>hello</sub> this is some text <sub>hi again<sub>`. I know I should use re.sub() but I'm unsure how to use it to correctly replace the string to my liking.

How would I do this? Thanks.

**Edit: Screenshots**

[image: input]
[image: result]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a backreference `\1` which refers to the matched group in the first argument in your pattern:

```
your_new_string = re.sub(r'\[subscript=(.+?)\]', r'<sub>\1</sub>', your_old_string)
```